# Something wrong with my batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I'm having to do a project on figurative language in Maroon 5 music, and decided to make a quiz. I am trying to be able to count how many questions were right. Here is my work so far, and there is a bug somewhere, but I don't know what it is.

```
@echo off
color 0f
:START
set Q=Q
cls
echo Maroon 5 Figuratve Language
echo ---------------------------
echo Options (Type a number and press ENTER):
echo 1) Take quiz
echo 2) Change color scheme
set /p Choice= 
if %Choice% == 1 GOTO GAME
if %Choice% == 2 GOTO COLOR
:COLOR
cls
echo Choose a color scheme.
echo 1) Black BG, White text
echo 2) White BG, black text
set /p color= 
if %color% == 1 GOTO 0F
if %color% == 2 GOTO F0
:0F
color 0f
GOTO start
:F0
color f0
GOTO start
:GAME
set qr=0
cls
goto Q1
:Q1
set qn=1
cls
echo What type of figurative language is "I can smell your scent from miles?"
echo a) Simile
echo b) Hyperbole
echo c) Metaphor
echo d) Personification
set /p Q1=
if %Q1% == b goto CORRECT
if NOT %Q1% == b goto INCORRECT
:CORRECT
set /a qr=%qr%+1
set /a qn=%qn%+1
goto %Q%%qn%
:INCORRECT
cls
echo Incorrect...
pause
set /a qn=%qn%+1
goto %Q%%qn%
:Q2
echo testing
echo %qn%
echo %qr%
pause
```

Comment: "Here is my work so far, and there is a bug somewhere, but I don't know what it is." So start debugging.

Comment: I don't suppose you could possibly narrow your question down a bit? Specifically, what output should you be seeing and what output are you actually seeing?

Comment: @SomethingDark If I get the answer correct, It should take me to the Q2 label and say

Comment: @SomethingDark Oh, I am dumb, I found the issue, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I can see a bug (there might be more in the code but this one is the first I can see ^^)! :D It's in the line `goto %Q%%qn%`. I've answered a similar question time ago: [How to put variable value inside another variable name in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696734/how-to-put-variable-value-inside-another-variable-name-in-batch/29696975?noredirect=1#comment47544531_29696975)

The point is that as your variables are being evaluated at parse time the interpreter doesn't know what's the value of `%Q%` and `%qn%`. You have to add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your script and surround your variables with `!...!` instead of `%...%`. This will force the interpreter to evaluate the values at **run time** considering any changes made to the variables so far.